# Styles was not loaded because its MIME type in React application

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, build, react-scripts

I have React application using Craco as configuration layer for create-react-app

Getting issue that styles are not loading randomly in production.

***Error***: `The stylesheet some.chunk.css was not loaded because its MIME type, "text/html", is not "text/css" in`

Already there are a lot of threads for this issue, search most of them
& solutions like thse don't help me:

- adding `<base href="/">`
- adding ***"homepage": "/"*** in package.json
- add type="css" for `link` tag, styles are atuomatically generated so this won't work

Do you guys have some ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In my project I solved it by replacing, in the link tag of the css file, `href=""` with `rel=""`.